# Emacs: Is there an easy way to copy files with ido navigation?

Tags: emacs, ido

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

1. Navigate to a buffer associated with a file
2. ^X^W (enter file ido file writing mode)
3. navigate via ido to another directory
4. Do something at this point to write a copy of the file in the navigated directory with the file name already associated with the buffer so I don't have to retype it.

I can't use ^F at this point because it writes to the original directory.

Bonus points if a similar method can be used to move files as well as copy them.

Comment: Whenever you're asking about how to use a piece of software, it is helpful to include a version.  In this case it's likely the same across most versions of Emacs that support ido, but if you're not sure, you should include the version :).  Nicely worded question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A simple variation of what you're after is of course this:

1. Navigate to a buffer
2. <kbd>C-x h M-w</kbd> to save the buffer contents in the kill ring
3. <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> visit a new file in another directory via `ido`
4. <kbd>C-y</kbd> to insert the contents of the original buffer
5. <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> save the buffer contents to file
6. <kbd>C-x k RET</kbd> kill the now obsolete buffer

This way a copy of the original buffer will be written to a different file without affecting the original buffer.